# how to save the state of fragment

Tags: android

I have a fragment with list:

```
public class GuestsList extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private GuestsListAdapter adapter;
    private FragmentTransaction fTrans;
    private Fragment guestFragment;
    private ArrayList<GuestBean> guests;
    private ListView list;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guestlist, null);

        guests = new ArrayList<GuestBean>();
        list = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.gustLIST);
        adapter = new GuestsListAdapter(getActivity(), guests);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        new NewThread().execute();

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        fTrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        guestFragment = new Guest();
        fTrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, guestFragment);
        fTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fTrans.commit();
    }

    public class NewThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
          //load data to guests
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

When you click on an item I create a new fragment Guest and old fragment were placed in backstack.
When I'm in a new fragment and click the back button opens fragment GuestsList which was in backstack and again the data downloaded from the Internet. I want them to be saved when creating a new fragment, and when you click on the back button to reload happens.

Comment: Maybe this can help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17252236/how-to-persist-fragment-data-after-backstack-transactions

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution is to use "add" instead of "replace" in your fragment transaction

```
 fTrans.add(R.id.content_frame, guestFragment);
```

It should not create new fragment when you will press back, but this is not very good solution if you have a lot of fragments (when I had many fragments and used "add" application lagged)

You may create your objects cache in custom Application class and get objects from application class.